# how does regex | and ? work with multiple characters?

Tags: regex, c++11

Edit: I'm using C++11 std::regex.

---

**How do I know if a regex "operator" applies to a single character, or a bunch of characters?**

Example 1:  If I have a regex of `apple|orange`, why does it not match:

```
applerange
applorange
```

Example 2:  If I have a regex of `loo?se`, wouldn't it means the previous characters are optional?  Why does it not match:

```
se
```

---

Given these 2 examples and my limited regex skills, I get around these 2 issues like this:

- In example 1, to have a single char "or" I would write: `appl[eo]range`
- In example 2, to have the first 3 chars optional, I would write: `(?:loo)?se`

Are these the proper solutions, or is there something more obvious?

Comment: The alternation operator `|` is low priority; the concatenated tokens `a`, `p`, `p`, `l`, `e` are one unit, and `orange` similar another set, separated by the `|`.  On the other hand, `?` binds tight, to the single preceding token, as in your `lose` or `loose` example.  They simply have different precedences.  You can override with `()`, but beware the implications of `()` for capturing groups.  So, your first option is valid and simple; you could write `appl(e|o)range` too.  The second option works with PCRE, but could be more general as `(loo)?se`.

Comment: yep, the above are the proper ones.

Comment: Beware what implications of `()` for capturing groups?

Comment: use captuirng groups if necessary otherwise you must go for a non-capturing group. Capturing group would reduce the performance or increases the time when comparing to non-capturing groups.

Comment: You don't indicate which language is hosting your regexes.  If you're using `grep`, then the grouping parentheses don't matter — they aren't treated specially.  However, if you're using `sed`, then each set of parentheses is a capture, and can be used separately in the replacement text.  Similarly in Perl — and other languages too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The alternation operator `|` alternates to the next boundary, which is either start/end of pattern, enclosing bracket or another alternation. i.e.

```
apple|orange
(apple)|(orange)
```

are identical in meaning and match either `"apple"` or `"orange"`.

To illustrate pipe as the boundary:

```
apple|orange|pear
(apple)|(orange)|(pear)
```

are identical in meaning.

The optional operator `?` applies to the preceding term. Without brackets, it's the previous single character. i.e.

```
loo?se
lo(o)?se
```

are identical in meaning, and match either `"lose"` or `"loose"`. The preceding term could be a character class or a bracketed (grouped) term too.